# Динамическая смена фона через hasClass

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть slick-slider, хочу сделать смену фона у главного контейнера при смене слайдера, завязанный на hasClass('slick-current'), добился только смены фона при hasClass у первого слайдера, если дальше листать, то цвет фона не меняется динамически с присваиванием класса .slick-current другому активному слайдеру.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#slide-1").hasClass("slick-current")) {
    $('.content').css("background-color", "yellow")
  }
  if ($("#slide-2").hasClass("slick-current")) {
    $('.content').css("background-color", "green")
  }
  if ($("#slide-3").hasClass("slick-current")) {
    $('.content').css("background-color", "red")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="single-item">
    <div class="slick-slide " id="slide-1" data-slick-index="0">
      <h3>1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="slick-slide slide-2" id="slide-2" data-slick-index="1">
      <h3>2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="slick-slide slide-3" id="slide-3" data-slick-index="2">
      <h3>3</h3>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а вы уверены, что у вас класс slick-current добавляется к другим элементам при прокрутке слайдера?

Comment: Да, slick-current - это класс активного в данный момент на экране элемента слайдера. Так же добавляется slick-active, но сути это не меняет.

Comment: ваш код отрабатывает один раз, при загрузке страницы. Вам нужно его в обработчик засунуть.

Comment: Подскажите? а то не особо силен в этом.

Comment: код, где переключаеютс слайды для этого нужен

Comment: $('.content').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    $(document).ready(function() {

        if($("#slide-1").hasClass("slick-current")){
            $('.content').css("background-color", "yellow")
        }
        if($("#slide-2").hasClass("slick-current")){
            $('.content').css("background-color", "green")
        }
        if($("#slide-3").hasClass("slick-current")){
            $('.content').css("background-color", "red")
        }
    });
});

Нашел в документации к слайдеру, теперь работает, но насколько верен такой код?

Comment: почти, добавть код в вопрос и посмотрите в мой ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходя из комментария ваш код должен выглядить примерно так.

```js
$('.content').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  if($("#slide1").hasClass("slick-current")){
    $('.content').css("background-color", "yellow") 
  } 
  
  if($("#slide-2").hasClass("slick-current")){
    $('.content').css("background-color", "green") 
  } 
  
  if($("#slide-3").hasClass("slick-current")){
    $('.content').css("background-color", "red") 
  }
});
```

Чтобы дать первому слайдеру сразу фон

```js
$(function() {
  if($("#slide1").hasClass("slick-current")){
    $('.content').css("background-color", "yellow");
  } 
});
```

Кстати можно было бы решить данную задачу с помощью css

```css
#slide1.slick-current {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#slide-2.slick-current {
  background-color: green;
}

#slide-3.slick-current {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Все работает, только вопрос еще один возник, слайдер 1 активен при загрузке страницу, но фон к нему подключается не сразу, а только на втором круге, как дать первому слайдеру сразу при загрузке, нужный фон?

Comment: @MaximVolkov обновил ответ

Comment: Не срабатывает задать фон первому при загрузке страницы :(